# Get browser result and source from VB

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, browser

First of all, i don't have a real good understanding about web programming. I try to get a html (succeed) source from vb. Here is the preview of the html:
[image]

As you can see (red arrow) that the list come from a javascript above  (in the same html). Here is the code :

```
function getplaylist(pageIndex)
{
    $("#list").empty();
    playlist(pageIndex,function(data){
        totalPage = data.totalpage;
        $("#pageIndex").text(pageIndex);
        $("#totalPage").text(totalPage);
        $.each(data.list,function(i,item){
            $("#list").append("<li num='"+ item.number +"'><table width='100%'><tr><td><p>"+ item.title +"</p><p>"+ item.artist +"</p></td></tr></table></li>");
        })
        $("#list li").on("click",function(){
            $(".caozuo").remove();
            var num = $(this).attr("num");
            $(this).append("<div class=\"caozuo\"><img src=\"images/ico_ding.png\" width=\"35\" onclick='dtop("+ num +")' /><img src=\"images/ico_del.png\" width=\"35\" onclick='ddelete("+ num +")' /></div>");
        })
    });
}
```

I want ask how to get number of the list (from picture, number of list is 5) from that html file, since the list is not really shown inside div of html file. Is that possible to get it? FYI, webserver is a machine which is not possible to make any changes.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, using browser automation. VB can access Chrome's DOM using Selenium or it can access Internet Explorer's DOM using the COM `IWebBrowser` interface - however if you're relatively new to programming you may find this task challenging.

Comment: I'm not a new programming, but also not an expert of VB. I'll try it. Just lack of knowledge (unfortunately) about web programming.. Thank you @Dai

Comment: I would argue that Browser Automation is not a web-programming task because most of the work is not concerned with the content of the HTML/DOM/JS/CSS but with desktop browser infrastructure development, which is a very different beast (e.g. you need to use COM on Windows for Internet Explorer if you don't want to go through WebDriver).